Enabling device encryption support in Windows 11, but errors: PCR 7 binding is not supported, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected
I want to encrypt a VHD (Virtual Hard Disk), or at least some folders in it, on Windows 11 Home using its native tools, but am receiving the following errors in Windows' System Information tool (when run as admin):
Device Encryption Support:
   PCR 7 binding is not supported, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected

There is a good QA here on Super User for the "Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s)" error, but before I spend time resolving that error, I want to ensure I can fix the "PCR 7 binding is not supported" error.
Here's what I've already done to try to fix this error, but nothing has helped so far:

Ensured the system BIOS is the latest version
Ensured system is using UEFI
Ensured Secure Boot is enabled
Ensured TPM 2.0 is enabled in the BIOS
Ensured Windows recognizes the firmware's TPM 2.0
Ensured Windows is completed updated
Ensured Windows recognizes that power mode S0 (Standby Low Power Idle) is supported
Ensured the Windows registry key KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BitLocker\PreventDeviceEncryption is not set to 1 (true)

What else can be done to resolve that error?

Update
That good Super User QA I mentioned is good, but Microsoft made some significant changes to Windows 11 that completely changes the usefulness of that QA.  So I wrote a new Super User QA for new versions of Windows 11:
Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected - how to handle now that Microsoft has removed common fix?

Home or Pro? What sort of VHD? "Device Encryption" and PCR7 should only be involved in encrypting the system volume, and it doesn't sound like that's what you're trying to do?

@grawity_u1686 Win11 Home. VHD created via Win11's System > Storage > Disks & Volumes > Create VHD, and then selecting VHDX for the VHD format.

@grawity_u1686 No MS account (only local).  Could that literally be the only issue?  I was going to create an MS account as a last resort after getting the other errors resolved to see if it was required... but you got me wondering if that could possibly be the only issue.  I strongly prefer not to create an MS account if it's not required.
